# Why do you need to put the label "day:" but not "name:" in my Swift function program?

Tags: swift, function

I started to learn Swift and I took the official book on Swift to read. I don't understand a particular idea behind the first example on **Functions**.

This is what the example code looks like:

```
  func greet(name: String, day: String) -> String {
        return "Hello \(name), today is \(day)."
    }
    greet("Bob", day: "Tuesday")
```

Which gives the correct output: "Hello Bob, today is Tuesday."

---

I don't understand why the code has "**day:**" in:

> greet("Bob", **day:** "Tuesday")

I mean, **the issue is**, if it has to have "day: Tuesday", then **why don't** we have **"name: Bob"**, instead we have simply "Bob".

---

---

### Things I've replaced** greet("Bob", day: "Tuesday") with:

1. greet(name: "Bob", day: "Tuesday")

   Error: Extraneous argument label 'name:' in call.
2. greet(name: "Bob", day: "Tuesday")

   Error: Missing argument label 'day:' in call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT for Swift 3+**
In Swift 3 and ulterior versions, the first argument label must also be used at call site by default, prefix label with _ in cases you don't want to have to specify argument name at call site.

**ORIGINAL Answer**

That's because by default, the name of the first parameter of a method (or a function since Swift 2) must not be written when you call this method/function.

That's because generally, it is included in the name of the function, in your case you might often have something like :

```
greetName(name:String, day:String) -> String
```

So that you can call :

```
greetName("Bob", day:"Tuesday")
```

If you absolutely wish the first parameter to require a name, you can do that in your method/function definition :

```
greet(name name:String, day:"Tuesday")
```

What you are doing here is specifying external parameter name for your parameter. 
Than, in your code, you will call :

```
greet(name:"Bob", day:"Tuesday")
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. Just to make sure I understand correctly if we have lets say:  func greet(day: String) -> String {
        return "today is \(day)."
    } 
    . Then all we do is write : greet("Tuesday") right???

Comment: Yes, you are right! (just don't forget the \ in front of the parentheses in your string )

Comment: Oh the editor doesn't show the \ in \(day) for some weird reasons :) Thanks a lot. Very helpful! Cheers!